# Ceating a Nautilus action button for opening current directory in Terminology, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, nautilus, terminology

I have installed terminology in my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. I changed my default Gnome terminal to Terminology using
`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`

and then selecting the `terminology` option in the window. It works fine for me when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> now, it open a new Terminology window instead of the default Gnome Terminal. The problem is that whenever I try to use the `Open in Terminal` button in the Nautilus File Manager window, it still uses the old Gnome Terminal. So, I tried to create a custom action using the File Manager config tools `fma-config-tools` after installing the package. Here are the images of the created action:
[image: Main Action view]

[image: Command View]

But the problem is that after doing this, and restarting the nautilus window using `nautilus -q` and `nautilus &`, the action button which should come into the right click menu does not show up. Please help me out with where I am going wrong in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot directly help with Nautilus actions. Fact is also that it is not anymore supported on later versions of nautilus, so it may not be a durable option.

However, you could try the nautilus python extension, `nautilus-open-any-terminal`. It can be found at https://github.com/Stunkymonkey/nautilus-open-any-terminal, where installation instructions are available. It does support Terminology, and as an added bonus, it can be triggered from within nautilus with a configurable shortcut key.